# Why does blowing on someone who is wet feel colder than on someone who is dry?

Tags: heat, water, temperature

The title says it all. If I'm standing in the wind and I'm wet, I feel much
colder than when I'm dry. This is true no matter how warm or cold the water.
Why is this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Evaporation of sweat from the skin surface has a cooling effect due to the latent heat of evaporation of water (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweat)). Basically, the heat is transfered from your skin to the water, the water then evaporates, taking with it a bit of the energy stored in it.

Further references [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoregulation)

Comment: Latent heat of evaporation refers to the energy cost of a phase transition?

Answer (score -4):

Our body is trying to cool down so when a strong wind blew, the coldness of the wind transferred to the heat in our body.Thus, our body will feel colder.

Comment: -1 for perpetuating the heat/coldness misconception. Heat is the energy that is being transfered from our body towards the environoment. No notion of "coldness" per se exists in thermal physics.