# If temperature is amount of kinetic energy of particles, then how can there be a cold breeze?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, everyday-life, kinetic-theory

When we put hands on A/C it gives cold winds. These winds have high kinetic energy but low temperature. How ? *don't confuse with A/C being heat pump , just an example, take antarctic blizzards. I can't understand the paradox of low temperature winds. Temperature is something defined by kinetic energy

Comment: I think you misunderstand several things.  First, it's not the total kinetic energy that relates to a temperature, but the mean kinetic energy in the bulk flow rest frame (i.e., in the frame where your "breeze" is not moving).  It relates to the randomized velocities about the mean.  Second, "cold" is a relative term.  If air at $60^{\circ}$ F blows past you, it will feel "cold," but if that air is comparable to the ambient air and/or your body temperature, it will feel warm.

Comment: Yes I do know , boltzman maxwell curve.  Also wether I say hot or cold , I can still rephrase the question in whichever way you might like. Of course I am talking relative to STP conditions.

Comment: @honeste_vivere there can be no denial that average AC wind kinetic energy is lower than STP air mean

Comment: There is a difference between the kinetic energy resulting from $\langle v^{2} \rangle$ and that from $\langle v \rangle^{2}$.  The former relates to temperature and the latter to dynamic/ram pressure.  The ram kinetic energy of the exhaust from an AC unit can be much larger than the ram kinetic energy of air in a still room.

Comment: The core misunderstanding in the question is addressed in [Why am I not burned by a strong wind?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/why-am-i-not-burned-by-a-strong-wind).

Comment: Suppose you are in a snowball fight. Your theory is that a snowball delivered to your target at 10 m/s is *much colder* than an identical snowball delivered to your target at 20 m/s, because the one has much lower kinetic energy than the other?

Comment: I can recall days when an 85F breeze would seem "cool", other times when a 65F breeze seemed "warm".  It's all relative.

Answer (score 63):

The average speed of an air molecule can be approximated by the following equation, which is exact only in the case of an ideal gas:

$$\langle v \rangle = \sqrt{\frac{2RT}{M}}$$

This means at $25$°C ($298$ K) air molecules will be moving randomly at an average speed of $\simeq 467$ m/s.

Let's say that the AC cools the air at $15$°C ($288$ K) before blowing it out into the room. From the above formula, the average molecular speed will then be $\simeq 459$ m/s.

When the AC blows out the air, it does so at $0.1-0.3$ m/s (1). This means that, in the worst case, a motion of $0.3$ m/s is superimposed to an average motion which is at around $460$ m/s, more than a *thousand times* faster.

You can then see how the movement of the air mass as a whole is negligible: what matters is the average molecular speed in the rest frame of the air mass.

Also, even if you use a simple fan instead of the AC you will perceive the air flux hitting your skin as colder. This is known as convective cooling. See for example [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72163/why-does-a-breeze-of-wind-make-us-feel-cooler) for a simple explanation.

(1) [Source](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_reasonable_indoor_air_velocities)

Comment: What about antarctic winds reaching speeds of several hundred meters per second? Does that make them hot?

Comment: @Jeff the world record for wind speed is 231mph ~103 m/s. Normally air has to be supersonic to start heating - over 300m/s

Comment: @Jeff Yes it does, meaning that if you measure your temperature in a fixed reference frame or in a frame moving with the air mass you get different results. Anyway, the highest wind speed ever registered on Earth is 113 m/s (Cyclone Olivia, 1996). You can try to work out what change this would bring in the temperature, but be careful that the $v$ in $\langle v \rangle$ is the absolute value of the velocity, while the wind will (presumably and approximately) blow in only one spatial direction.

Comment: So does this mean that in the case of AC, assuming it was blowing out an ideal gas, the majority of the air it moved would be pretty much not moving at all with a few particles moving at very great speed?

Comment: @SGR no... the NET flow of the air, the actual "macro-scale" flow of air that you feel is the wind speed, but the air molecules are moving in all directions. Its abit like polystyrene beads on a surface of flowing water.. the net movement of the beads will follow the flow of the water, but the beads will move relative to one another too depending on what you fix as your frame of reference.

Comment: @valerio92 I think you mean 459.3 m/s, not 460.

Comment: @Tim (and valerie), seems max wind speed bring about almost the same debates that record temperature long has.  But I doubt you're including upper air wind speeds and definitely are [excludes remote-sensed speeds](https://extremeplanet.me/2012/07/03/highest-winds-measured-in-several-different-tornadoes/) fairly near the ground.  But that doesn't matter, the point is the conclusions, which seem solid enough :-)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Actually all I did was google max wind speed earth and look at the "one true answer" box :P I didn't feel there was much need for an especially reliable source, as long as what I found was significantly below the 300 m/s he'd suggested.

Comment: @Setop They are the same to 2sf to be fair - which is all we have the temperature measured to in the example. 460 is probably a better answer.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I didn't want to argue about the record, I just wrote what I recalled :-) (I looked it up some time ago to answer another question). Tim is right: if you just Google 'wind speed record', 103 m/s comes out, but reading the Wiki article you discover that this value is actually the second highest ever measured. Anyway, as you said yourself, both values are equivalent for the purpose of the argument.

Answer (score 14):

There are two things at play here.

### The Nature of Heat

Temperature, is to do with random, undirected motion.  So for example, in room temperature gas, you can have individual molecules which themselves are moving at $100~\textrm{ms}^{-1}$, however on average, the velocity is zero.

When you have a body of colder air moving, it means on average their kinetic energy is lower, but they have a net "drift" velocity.  That is the particles have random velocities, which corresponds to the heat, but because they've been "blown", they have an average velocity of maybe $5~\textrm{ms}^{-1}$ in one particular direction.

### Why a breeze cools us down

The fact that a breeze cools us down has only a small amount to do with the temperature of the air.  Consider your hand, sat in still air.  Your hand will give some thermal energy to a layer of air surrounding it.  (In the process of warming up that air, your hand will cool down).  Now if the air is still, then that's the end of the story.  However when there's a breeze, this layer of air that you've warmed up, gets carried away.  It gets replaced with some new cold air, which your hand can then give heat to again, which cools your hand off again.  When there's a breeze, your hand is constantly supplied with new air that it can give heat to.  And so it's less that the air is a lower temperature, it's that as soon as it gets warmed up, it's replaced by a new set of cold air.

Just for fun, let's consider another similar effect.  Say there's a little water on your hand.  When this water evaporates, it requires heat from your hand, and so the evaporating water will cool you down.  In still air, eventually the air will start to contain more water vapour, and so the evaporation process will be slower.  However if we introduce a breeze, then we are bringing in fresh new dry air, so the evaporation process can occur faster, and so more heat can be taken away.  This process is why if you lick your hand, and then blow on it, it cools it down.

Comment: If temperature has little to do then  how can there be "Hot winds"?

Comment: Emphasis "little" to do with it.  You still need there to be a temperature gradient, for heat to flow from your hand to the air.

Comment: @user154547 Hot winds are hot air masses moving along a pressure gradient. The speed of the moving air mass has little to do with its temperature.

Comment: @valerio92 to add: unless air is passing really (supersonic) fast

Comment: With strong enough wind it is possible to die from hypotermia on a hot day - that is one of the reasons why motorbike riders ride with body folly covered.

Comment: @Suma That's because a "hot day" is still often cooler than your body temperature.  The faster you go the greater the convective heat transfer, and therefore the lower temperature your skin can get relative to your body temperature.  Even if the air is only a few degrees less, if you have a lot of exposed skin it could add up to a lot of heat loss.  You probably wouldn't want to ride exposed in above-body temperatures either, your would overheat really quickly since the convection would transfer heat from the air to your body.

Comment: @JMac  talkin of desert dunes

Answer (score 1):

The crux is that temperature is the *undirected* movement of particles.

Consider a very easy example of two air molecules flying with $100m/s$ away from each other, one in +$x$-direction, the other in $-x$-direction. The mean directed velocity is then $0$, however, the mean undirected velocity which corresponds to temperature is +$100m/s$.

Now suppose you accelerate both particles by $+50m/s$, so that one has a velocity of $-50m/s $ and the other $+150m/s$. The mean directed velocity is then $+50m/s$, which is the velocity of the breeze. In contrast the undirected remains at $(150+50)/2 = 100m/s$ - the temperature of the system has not changed.

Answer (score -1):

A breeze is not "a bunch of air molecules moving in that direction".  A breeze is a *wave* of pressure.

The speed of air molecules is on the same order as the speed of sound.  They are flying around smashing into things and mostly bouncing off.  You are surrounded by a barrage of minute "meteors" that are smashing into your skin and bouncing off in all directions.

Well, these meteors are mostly bouncing off *each other*, because at 1 atm things are so dense that the average molecule travels 68 nm before hitting another molecule.

The only thing stopping it from knocking you flying is that you are being smashed into on all sides uniformly all of the time.

A perfect vacuum is just the effect of the *other side* smashing into you and pushing you that way, without the support of the molecules on the vacuum side.  A vacuum cleaner reduces air pressure by a tiny amount, and it causes a pretty huge force this way.

A "wind" is a relatively tiny wave of higher pressure on top of this violet stew of air molecules.  We feel it because on the side it is coming from, the pressure is higher, and on the other side it is lower.  Even a hurricane is a relatively small change in pressure, and is enough to pick up and destroy houses, trees, cars and people.  The strongest hurricane comes from about a 10% difference in atmospheric pressure!  That pressure difference from the edge to the center is enough to power the winds of that entire storm.

A 10 km/h wind is traveling at 1% of the speed of sound, which is roughly how fast air molecules move.  That macroscopic motion is a tiny contribution to the average kinetic energy of the molecules of air; it has roughly 2% more KE than the same air stationary.

A 100km/h wind is now going at 10% of the speed of sound.  As KE is square of velocity, at that point we are talking about 20% more KE than the same air stationary.

You'd have to approach 700 km/h for the wind to have as much KE from its macroscopic "wind" motion as it does from it's microscopic "vibration" motion.

Now, as another poster has mentioned, the velocity of air molecules is actually a touch higher than the speed of sound; sound is a wave, so it isn't going to propogate at the exact same speed as air molecules are (it will travel a bit slower).  But it gives you the right order of magnitude.

Comment: A breeze is a relatively small deviation of the mean velocity from zero. It is *not* a pressure phenomena or a wave.

Comment: @dmckee I think he may be miswording it or misinterpreting it.  Pressure differences are highly related to the wind (though I'm not a meteorologist and don't know enough about it to say if it's a thermal action creating pressure difference that drives the wind, or thermal variations drive movement which creates pressure differentials, etc.).  Either way I agree it isn't accurate as is.

Comment: @dmckee A breeze is a relatively small deviation of the mean velocity from zero with a corresponding pressure gradient that allows that velocity to propagate (in a wave like fashion). Saying a breeze is not a pressure phenomena is like saying light is only a small deviation in electric field, it's not a magnetic phenomena .

Comment: @Rick It is only the relative motion between myself and the bulk of the air that make a breeze. That relative motion can be generated by weather pattern (which are indeed driven by pressure differences) or by the motion of a conveyance that I ride through a placid indoor space. Nor is wave-like behavior necessary: a steady-state flow is still a breeze. There is a lot here that could be part of a nice discussion of wind in general, but it's poking around *"where does a natural wind come from"* instead of the thermal transfer from moving air question the OP asked.

Comment: @dmckee yeah, I agree that the pressure discussion is rather tangential to the OP's question.