# If an ice cube moved really fast in a vacuum, would it melt?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, inertial-frames

I learned that thermal energy is just the kinetic energy of the individual particles of a substance. What if I give the ice cube kinetic energy, not by heating it, but rather by making it move very fast? Then the ice particles will gain kinetic energy because they are now moving very quickly, translationally through space. Therefore, since they have more kinetic energy then the temperature must also increase. Since the temperature increases it melts. I feel like this must be wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: No it would not. Translation of the center of mass of an object is not the same thing as heating it up.

Comment: @JonCuster but doesn't each individual particle have its own center of mass? Each one of those particles has more kinetic energy because the whole ice cube is moving. So how is that kinetic energy of translation different than the kinetic energy of heat?

Comment: The velocity distribution of the particles _relative to each other_ is what determines the temperature of the body. So one can subtract out the velocity of the center of mass.

Comment: An ice cube at rest from your point of view is moving near the speed of light in many other inertial frames. You seem to be thinking that motion is absolute, but it’s not.

Comment: Heat will be produced during acceleration until the body reaches a constant speed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If temperature is related to average kinetic energy in an ideal gas, then does speeding up the gas container affect its temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487453/)

Comment: Realistically, there is no such thing as a perfect vacuum. So the mean free path of any particle is finite. Eventually, there will be a collision that generates heat.

Answer (score 1):

No, the orderly movement of the body as whole
does not contribute to its thermal energy.
Only the random movement of its particles does.

Quoted from ["Thermal Energy | Energy Fundamentals"
at University Leipzig](https://home.uni-leipzig.de/energy/energy-fundamentals/06.htm) (emphasis by me):

> In thermodynamics, the internal energy $U$ is an
> energy form that results from the **random** motion
> of microscopic particles in a system. This thermal
> energy increases with increasing temperature $T$.