# Why is the cloth cooled to a temperature below that of the hot wind?

Tags: thermodynamics

> When a wet cloth is hung up in a hot wind in the desert, it is cooled by evaporation to a temperature that may be or so below that of the air. Discuss this process in light of the second law of thermodynamics.

I come up with the following facts: Think of the cloth and the water on it separately. The cloth is a closed system(no matter exchange between the system and the environment). This system transfer its heat into the water since its temperature decreases. The water on the cloth can be also thought of as a closed system. Then since the temperature of the water increases, it absorbs heat from both the cloth and the hot wind.

I don't know whether they are true, and I really want to know why the cloth can cooled to a temperature below that of the air.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: @Name no, it's not

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16549/23473

Comment: @ACuriousJim There is not a single human involved in the problem

Comment: @user43796 The presence of humans is irrelevant

Comment: The answer is in pretty much any text on StatMech or Chemistry which mentions things like "energy of phase transition."